# Run-Time Error '91' - Declared objects correctly and same syntax works in lines above

Tags: excel, vba, object, runtime-error

I am at my wits end trying to decode this error I am getting.

In the syntax below, the line which throws up the error is `NumColumnsTarget = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column`

As far as I can tell, I have assigned all the objects correctly. One thing I have noticed is that changing the order in which the Range variables are declared in (Ie: `NumRowsTarget, NumColumnsTarget, NumColumnsLOP, NumRowsLOP` as opposed to `NumRowsLOP, NumColumnsLOP, NumRowsTarget, NumColumnsTarget`) will change which variable throws the Run-Time error up and I am lost for a reason why. Any thoughts?

```
Option Explicit

Sub MergeRecords()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim TargetRecordArray(), LOPRecordArray() As Variant
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i, j As Integer
Dim LOPSerialNo, TargetSerialNo As String

Dim NumRowsLOP, NumColumnsLOP, NumRowsTarget, NumColumnsTarget As Range

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("LOP Records")

With ws
    NumRowsLOP = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    NumColumnsLOP = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
End With

Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Target Records")

With ws
    NumRowsTarget = .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
    NumColumnsTarget = .Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
End With

End Sub
```

Edit: I am a fool. Thanks to all.

Comment: `Dim NumRowsLOP, NumColumnsLOP, NumRowsTarget, NumColumnsTarget As Range` only the last variable is defined as Range, all other are definied as Variant

Comment: You need to declare the type of each variable separately.

Comment: Whereas you wanted all of them to be `Long`.

Comment: You have to specify `As range` for all required variables

Comment: @VincentG Then it will not work for all four lines.

Comment: @GSerg Your right

Comment: `NumColumnsTarget` is declared as a Range object (the others in that line are of Type Variant), but `Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column` returns a `Long`.  Hence the error with this variable.